# Global Arraylist index out of range issue

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

I am facing an issue where I am getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBound` on `photoViewAttacherList.get(position)`. Now I can easily handle by catching the error, but I am not able to understand why it is happening at the very first place. Here is the code of the adapter. It's strange because I am adding the `new PhotoViewAttacher` in `instantiate` function which will be called for every new item added.

```
public class FullImagePagerAdaptor extends PagerAdapter {


private final LayoutInflater inflater;
private final ArrayList<String> urls;
private final Context context;
private final ArrayList<String> descriptions;
private ArrayList<PhotoViewAttacher> photoViewAttacherList;
private TogglePagingListener togglePagingListener;

public FullImagePagerAdaptor(Context context, ArrayList<String> urls, ArrayList<String>
        descriptions, TogglePagingListener togglePagingListener) {
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.urls = urls;
    this.context = context;
    this.descriptions = descriptions;
    photoViewAttacherList = new ArrayList<>();
    this.togglePagingListener = togglePagingListener;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return urls.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == object;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_full_image, container, false);
    TextView description = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_full_image_description);
    ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar_full_image);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
    if (descriptions != null && descriptions.get(position) != null) {
        description.setText(descriptions.get(position));
    }

    Log.d("sg","Instantiating Pager:with position" + position);

    ImageUtility.loadImage(context, urls.get(position),
            GlobalVariables.IMAGE_TYPE.URL, 0, 0,
            imageView, progressBar);
    photoViewAttacherList.add(new PhotoViewAttacher(imageView));


    // THIS IS WHERE ARRAYINDEXOUTOFBOUND EXCEPTION IS GETTING RAISED
    photoViewAttacherList.get(position).setOnMatrixChangeListener(new PhotoViewAttacher.OnMatrixChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMatrixChanged(RectF rect) {
            if(isImageZoomed(position))
                togglePagingListener.disablePaging();
            else
                togglePagingListener.enablePaging();
        }
    });
    container.addView(v);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    photoViewAttacherList = null;
    container.removeView((View) object);
}

public boolean isImageZoomed(int pos) {
    return checkZoom(pos) != 1.0;
}

public float checkZoom(int pos){
    return photoViewAttacherList.get(pos).getScale();
}

public interface TogglePagingListener {
    public void enablePaging();
    public void disablePaging();
}
```

Comment: You can first check the `position` is it start from zero or not

Comment: If the `position' starts from 1 then, you can `position-1` when you get the element from list

Answer (score 0):

From your code I understand one thing that, you want to add a new `PhotoViewAttacher` object to your existing list and add a listener `setOnMatrixChangeListener` to that object.
For this you are adding that object in list and then accessing the same again from list, rather you can have an object created and add to list and to the same object you can add event listener. This is a clean approach.

`position` should also be recalculated to know exactly where the element was inserted but this is `final` so you can not change it so declare a new variable for it.

**Snippet:**

```
    PhotoViewAttacher photoObj =  new PhotoViewAttacher(imageView);
    photoViewAttacherList.add(photoObj);

    final int newPositionInserted = photoViewAttacherList.size() - 1; //Recalculating the position here  to know exactly where the object was added
    // Here you can use the object which was created so you do not need to worry about the index also
    photoObj.setOnMatrixChangeListener(new PhotoViewAttacher.OnMatrixChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMatrixChanged(RectF rect) {
            if(isImageZoomed(newPositionInserted))
                togglePagingListener.disablePaging();
            else
                togglePagingListener.enablePaging();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I eliminated the `List` all together and passed the `PhotoViewAttacher` directly to `isImageZoomed`. The problem was because it was directly instantiating for position 1.